How do I revert an edit to my question?
Someone else edited my question inappropriately (IMO).
What is the right way to revert their changes?
There is a Rollback link for all the other revisions in the history but not for the top one, just Source|Edit|Link.
What I ended up doing was clicking on Edit, then selecting the previous revision from the drop-down menu, then saving the previous version. Is that the right way?

The idea of the rollback link is that you can roll back to a particular revision. So in the revision history choose the second most recent one and click rollback on that one to undo the most recent edit.

If your question was edited by someone with a diamond after their name (a moderator), you'd better not revert it without asking them first why they performed that edit.

It looks like an excellent edit. And the editor does not earn any "edit points", whatever those are.

@sds You stop earning reputation from edits when you get either 1000 total reputation from edits, or you hit 2k reputation; whichever comes first.  This is covered here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Rather than thinking of rolling back an edit (i.e., from a given revision), the system thinks of rolling back to a previous version/revision.
For example, if you think that Revision 2 was a bad edit, then you should rollback to Revision 1 by going to that revision in the edit history and clicking Rollback on Revision 1.
Here's how it looks on your question here:

Since Revision 2 is the current revision, you can’t “rollback” to it — only to previous ones.
